Solc too slow compiling
The solc compiler that I'm using (0.8.21) is taking too much time to compile. It's compiling 20 files for a foundry test campaign in ~90 seconds when it should be milliseconds.
Any ideas on what I should check/modify to improve this and/or reduce the size of the binary file?
I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.4.1.
Thanks!


It may not be a foundry nor solc problem. I use 0.8.20 to 0.8.25 and i compile up to 60 files in less than 10 seconds.
Maybe uninstall, do a clean up and reinstall ?

It was taking between 2-3 mins before, I formatted my mac, and now this is the time it takes with factory settings and only the necessary to run foundry. @Torof
